# How do I write a message timestamp to a log file?

Tags: c++, logging, time, timestamp, c++-chrono

I'm trying to create a logging file for my C++ program. My goal is to put two timestamps at two points of my program and print in a file the CPU time period between these two points. I'm doing this because I want to know which parts of my code are the most time consuming so I can make improvements (so there may be several chunks of code I want to measure). So far, I've made a function that, when called, prints a string that I pass as an argument, to a file:

```
#define LOGFILE "myprog.log"
void Log (std::string message){
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open(LOGFILE, std::ofstream::out | std::ios::app);
    ofs << message << std::endl;
    ofs.close();
}
```

However, I'm having difficulty figuring out how to print the CPU timestamp. Firstly, I don't know what time measurement format I should use (should I use the chrono or the time_t types?) I'm trying to print a time period so it would be helpful if there was a type for duration (I've tried chrono::duration but it seems to require C++11 support). Secondly, given I know what type to use, how do I print it to the file? Is there a way to cast that type to a string? Or can I pass it directly to my function and print it somehow?

This has troubled me a lot the last couple of days and I can't seem to figure it out, so any input would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A great place to start, until it makes it's way in to the C++ standard, is [Howard Hinnant's Date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Comment: If you really want to profile your program, why not use traditional tools designed for that purpose?

Comment: Note: Get the time before monkeying around with the logfiles. Time you spend opening the file etc... will impact your results.

Comment: @LIghtnessRacesinOrbit Care to explain? How exactly do you assume I know what you are talking about?

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ekter15 Maybe if you ask nicely...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Get a CPU Timestamp

You'll want to use `std::chrono::system_clock` to get this timestamp. *Do not use `std::chrono::steady_clock` or `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`*, as those are for making high-precision timing measurements, and do not guarantee fidelity or accuracy to wall-clock time.

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
//now is a time_point object describing the instant it was recorded according to your system clock
```

#### Print this CPU Timestamp in a readable format

In C++20, this is pretty trivial.

```
std::string formatted_time = std::format("{0:%F_%T}", now);
ofs << formatted_time << ": " << message << std::endl;
```

- `%F` is a substitute for `%Y-%m-%D`, which will output year-month-day in ISO format, i.e. `2018-10-09`.
- `%T` is the same for `%H:%M:%S`, which will output a time, i.e. `17:55:34.786`

See the specification for [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) and [`std::formatter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter) for more information about how to specify these parameters.

As of December 2020, no major compilers support the `<format>` library, yet, so as an alternative you can use [`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), which is a standalone implementation of the library.

#### Prior to C++20

Consider [Howard Hinnant's `date` library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), most of which is being incorporated into C++20 as a new part of the `chrono` library. The `format` function found in that library uses the same syntax as suggested above for the C++20 version, although without integration with `std::format`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. How can I use the C++20 features though? I'm using a CMakeLists.txt file to make my project.

Comment: `error: ‘format’ is not a member of ‘std::chrono’`

Comment: @Cerin Between when I wrote this answer and now, they integrated the `std::chrono::format` functionality into the more general `std::format` and `std::formatter` functionality. I've updated the answer to reflect the changes they made, but I had to spitball on the format string because none of the compilers I looked at support the `<format>` library features from C++20 yet.

Answer (score 3):

For the record:

If C++20 features are not available, as in my case, you can use the following:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

time_t now = time(nullptr) ;
cout << put_time(localtime(&now), "%T") << endl ;
```

put_time is defined in iomanip library, look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time, and time_t and localtime are from the ctime, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime

Answer (score 2):

I'm usually use my implementation for such things.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>


// strftime format
#define LOGGER_PRETTY_TIME_FORMAT "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

// printf format
#define LOGGER_PRETTY_MS_FORMAT ".%03d"


// convert current time to milliseconds since unix epoch
template <typename T>
static int to_ms(const std::chrono::time_point<T>& tp)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto dur = tp.time_since_epoch();
    return static_cast<int>(duration_cast<milliseconds>(dur).count());
}


// format it in two parts: main part with date and time and part with milliseconds
static std::string pretty_time()
{
    auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t current_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);

    // this function use static global pointer. so it is not thread safe solution
    std::tm* time_info = std::localtime(&current_time);

    char buffer[128];

    int string_size = strftime(
        buffer, sizeof(buffer),
        LOGGER_PRETTY_TIME_FORMAT,
        time_info
    );

    int ms = to_ms(tp) % 1000;

    string_size += std::snprintf(
        buffer + string_size, sizeof(buffer) - string_size,
        LOGGER_PRETTY_MS_FORMAT, ms
    );

    return std::string(buffer, buffer + string_size);
}
```

It returns current time in format: `2018-09-23 21:58:52.642`.

Yes it requires `--std=c++11` or above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I use the C++11 features? (I'm using a CMakeLists.txt file)

Comment: @ekter15
`TARGET_COMPILE_FEATURES(${MyProject} PRIVATE cxx_std_11)`
or
`SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`

Comment: lol. Suffers from the infamous Y2020 bug. Casting milliseconds::count() to int overflows every 4 years, causing the displayed milliseconds to be negative in 2022. Handling of the milliseconds count should either explicitly be int64_t, or change to_ms to return auto and remove the static_cast<int>().  I believe the decltype of milliseconds::count() is specified by the  C++ 20 standard  (guaranteed to be a minimum of 52 bits, which seems to be suspiciously chosen to allow implementations to use double!).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more manual approach, this is what I've used before

```
char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *lt = localtime(&t);

snprintf(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", lt->tm_mon+1, lt->tm_mday, lt->tm_year%100, lt->tm_hour, lt->tm_min, lt->tm_sec);
```

Then just output *buffer*, which now contains string representation of time, to your file.